# show a div when click an input button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show a div in a component when I click on an input button in another component.

For example :

In the add component, I have an input: `<input #openDiv>` and I need when I click or focus it this to show this component:

```
<div-component [focus]="openDiv"></div-component>
```

This is my `div-component`:

```
export class divComponent implements OnInit , AfterViewInit {

  @Input() focus: ElementRef;
}
```

How can I sovle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`<div-component *ngIf="showDiv"></div-component>`

and:

`<input #openDiv (focus)="showDiv = true" (click)="showDiv = true" />`

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2p2je

Note, you can also use `(focusout)="showDiv = false"` to hide the div when it loses focus. Further ***ngIf** removed the element from DOM. If you want to keep the element in your DOM use `[hidden]="!showDiv"`.

Comment: i want handle that on that component . how can i pass that input ot the conponent and find state that input ?